# Textarea showing Error message when is not needed

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a textarea which is required to fill to submit the form and i had defined an error message to show. But the problem is that when the model is not empty (has text in there) the error message is being shown too. I want to avoid that setting a condition for the "required-err" message that (if comment != '') doesn't show it but i do not know how to do it. Any help?

```
<textarea class="span11" ng-required="true" ng-model="comment" tooltip-message
                              placement="bottom"
                              required-err="Error"
                              placeholder="Enter text..."></textarea>
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ? where did required-err come from ? I am not seeing it in the options for textarea https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/textarea

Comment: The thing is that this is code that i'm dealing with but isn't mine. You mean that required-err should be a directive defined somewhere in the project?

Comment: maybe, because AFAIK is not part of html, and it is not part of default angular. So maybe it is something custom, or in a library, or maybe I didn't know about that option in html/angularjs (but I am googling it and I can't find anything). So if it is something custom, yeah we need that code to help you